# Gitで２つのリポジトリを統合したい

Tags: git, tortoisegit

どうにも困っておりまして、質問させていただきます。

現在、違うサーバにAというリポジトリと、Bというリポジトリがあり、これをAのサーバに統合したいのですが、
A--.git
　|--develop--B--.git
　　　　　　　|-home
としたときに、BがAのリポジトリに認識されず、commit,pushした後、別の端末でAをクローンすると、
A--.git
　|--develop--B
となり、Bの中身を取得することができませんでした。
別のリポジトリだからだと思い、git remote set-urlでリモートリポジトリを変更したのですが、効果がありませんでした。

履歴を残す必要があり、以下の記事を読んだりしたのですが、どのようにすればよいのかわかりません。
https://chaika.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/06/04/173401

どうかご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: サーバを1つにする => リポジトリを統合する必要がある、というわけではないと思いますが(何を指してサーバと呼んでいるかにも依りますが、例えばgithubは1リポジトリごとにサーバが立っているわけではないですよね)、実際に行いたいことが「サーバを統合する」「リポジトリを統合する」のどちらであるか不明確であると感じました。

Comment: 表現がわかりづらく申し訳ございませんでした。本番と検証環境のgitを統合したい、という要望だったのですが、検証用のサーバと本番用のサーバが別個に作られており、AサーバのAリポジトリのAブランチを、BサーバのBリポジトリのなかに取り込みたい、というのがやりたかったことでした。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git リポジトリの中に git repository を物理的に配置した場合、それは git submodule が実体化されたものであると認識して動作するようになっています。 submodule は、端的に言えば、ディレクトリ構造をコミットするかわりに別リポジトリのコミットの sha-id のみを記録しておく機能です。

submodule ではなく、 git の履歴自体を取り込みながら、とある統合コミットがあって、それは二つのリポジトリの歴史のマージコミットであり、一方がもう一方のサブディレクトリに配置されているようなことが実現したい場合、これは git subtree を用いるのが良いです。

```
git subtree add --prefix=サブディレクトリへのパス リモート ブランチ
```

で実行します。

### 具体例

#### 準備スクリプト

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf A
mkdir A

( cd A
  git init
  echo hoge > hoge
  git add -A
  git commit -m "init hoge"
)

rm -rf B
mkdir B

( cd B
  git init
  echo fuga > fuga
  git add -A
  git commit -m "init fuga"
)
```

#### A リポジトリ

```
.
└── hoge
```

#### B リポジトリ

```
.
└── fuga
```

#### 実行スクリプト

```
cd A
git remote add B ../B
git fetch --all
git subtree add --prefix=B B master
```

#### 結果

```
$ cd A
$ tree
.
├── B
│   └── fuga
└── hoge
$ git log --oneline --graph
*   d05554a Add 'B/' from commit 'c4945e3a01ecfd7e9ed88c76222c52a1e10c3235'
|\  
| * c4945e3 init fuga
* a842d05 init hoge
```

Comment: subtreeを使って無事に移行することができました！ありがとうございました！なんとなくですが、submoduleとsubtreeの違いも理解できました！

Comment: @はとり お役にたてたら何よりです。もしこの回答で質問が解決した場合は[回答の承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)をお願いできますでしょうか。システム的に、問題が解決済みであることを示すことができます。