# 2つのrepositoryを新しいrepositoryのサブディレクトリにして管理したい

Tags: git

aaaとbbbという2つのリポジトリがあり，これらを統合して1つの新しいリポジトリとして下記のように管理したいと考えています．

```
new-repo
├.git
├aaa
└bbb
```

aaaとbbbの歴史も残しつつ，new-repoとして新しく統合したリポジトリを作る方法として，どういう方法があるでしょうか？
歴史を残すというのは，例えばnew-repoの直下で `git log` したときにaaaとbbbの歴史が同時に見れるようにしたい，ということです．

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git subtree を使うと他のリポジトリの歴史を保ったまま、サブディレクトリとしてマージできます。 新しくリポジトリを作成し、そこで aaa と bbb をそれぞれ subtree add してやればできると思います。

git subtree add は、 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/44470/754 などを参考するといいかもです。

Comment: ありがとうございます．無事にできそうです．

Comment: @maeken2010 お役にたてたならなによりです。この回答で問題が解決したならば、これを承認していただけますでしょうか。 (https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) システム的に、質問(問題)が解決済みであることを示すことができます。

Comment: わかりました！ついでに質問です．aaaのとあるremoteブランチも統合したい場合はaaa側でcheckoutしておかないといけない、又はmasterにmergeしておかないといけないでしょうか？

Comment: @maeken2010 リモートブランチということは、リモートリポジトリが存在すると思っています。 subtree add は、 git remote によって管理されるリモートと、そのリモート上のブランチを指定して実行します。

Comment: なので、たとえば aaa が github にて管理されていたならば、新しいリポジトリにて、 git remote add aaa-origin git@github.com:myteam/myrepo のようにして、github 上のリポジトリを直接リモートとして追加し、 git fetch --all などでリモートのブランチ情報を持ってきた後に、 git subtree add --prefix=aaa aaa-origin aaa-branch などとすれば、いけると思います。

Comment: あ，なるほど！わかりました．ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

こんな感じでできると思います。

new-repo を作成:

```
% mkdir new-repo
% cd new-repo
% git init
% git commit -m 'Initial commit' --allow-empty
```

aaa リポジトリをリモートリポジトリとして追加して、ブランチとして作成、ディレクトリに移動:

```
% git remote add aaa <aaaリポジトリ>
% git fetch aaa
% git checkout -b aaa aaa/master
% mkdir aaa
% mv * aaa
% git add .
% git commit -m 'directory aaa'
```

bbb リポジトリも同様にして、その後 aaa と bbb を master にマージ:

```
% git checkout master
% git merge --allow-unrelated-histories aaa
% git merge --allow-unrelated-histories bbb
```

Comment: mv の際に、 . からはじまるファイルが aaa/bbb のトップレベルに追加されていた場合は、たぶんそれらは mv されないのではないか、と思っています。

Comment: そうですね。まあその辺はよしなに…。というか git subtree なんてコマンドがあったんですね。知りませんでした。

Comment: addだけではなく、元々のレポジトリへのコミット分を分割して push まで、やろうと思えばできるっぽいので、機会があれば使ってみるのもいいかもしれません。